# Close angular modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jqgrid, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new in angularJs and I have an application that using angular modal and jqGrid. (I know that this is not good. But for some reason I must work with two, now.)

My modal content loads with a templateUrl.

```
<div ng-controller="SearchPerson as ctrl">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <table id="list"></table>
        <div id="pager"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="$close()">CLOSE</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ctrl.CLOSE()">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and for create I have this code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url: "/Home/List",
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: [" ", "FirstName", "LastName"],
        colModel: [
            {
                width: 30,
                sortable: false,
                formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                    return '<a href="javascript:ctrl.Select();">SELECT</a>';
                },
            },
            {
                name: "FirstName",
                width: 60,
            },
            {
                name: "LastName",
                width: 90
            }
        ],
        jsonReader: {
            page: "Page",
            total: "Total",
            records: "Records",
            root: "Rows",
            repeatitems: false,
            cell: "cell",
            id: "id",
            userdata: "userdata",
        },
        pager: "#pager",
    });
});
```

and for open modal I write this code:

```
angular.module('AngularModal', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    angular.module('AngularModal').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal) {

        $scope.open = function (size) {

            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: '/Home/SearchGrid',
                controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                size: size,
                backdrop: 'static',
            });

            modalInstance.result.then(function () {
                // 
            }, function () {
                //
            });
        };

    });
    angular.module('AngularModal').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
        $scope.ok = function () {
            $modalInstance.close();
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };

    });

    angular.module('AngularModal').controller('SearchPerson', function ($http, $modalStack) {

    });
```

What I want is: when I click SELECT link in my grid, alert FirstName and then close the modal.

How to do this?

It is noteworthy that when I click CLOSE button, modal close. And also when I click "Save changes" buton, the modal will close.
But when I click SELECT link, modal does not close. While I write both ng-click of SELECT and "Save Change" for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would definitely not work. For `ng-click`, the context of the expression is the current `$scope`, while for `href="javascript:expression"` the context is the global, or saying `window`.

For your situation, I would definitely suggest you try some other grid libraries which are more compatible with AngularJS (like http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/ or http://ui-grid.info/). That may save tons of time.

Otherwise, if you really really insist on using jqGrid, you may need to wrap it into a directive manually by yourself. In your application, you may need to consider how to "angularize" the html snippet generated for the formatter function.

```
formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    var html = '<a ng-click="ctrl.Select()">SELECT</a>';
    var linkFunc = $compile(html);
    linkFunc(scope);         // the scope in which you have the `ctrl.Select()` function.
    return html;
},
```

$compile: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Then you will be able to call angular scope functions.

However, in my opinion, this is not a good practice. If any possible, find a replacement library, please.

Comment: I can't access to $compile in this code. I get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $compile is not defined

Comment: @Tavousi You need to wrap the code inside a directive, then you can inject the `$compile` service into the directive.